# Display a Views slideshow only if more than one image

Tags: views, panels, media

I have a content type with an image field that allows multiple values. I have a View that displays the images using [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow).

If there is only one image added to a node, I just want to display it as a static image. If multiple images have been added, I want to display the slideshow View.

I'm using a [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) Page override for this content type, so I can use a visibility rule for the Views slideshow pane (i.e. only display if number of images > 1). But I'm not sure how to check the image field to see if there is more than one image for the current node?

Am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd have to do some custom coding to get that result. To simplify, you'd have to make a separate field for the single image option.